# Conditional validation for Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

I have a nested form and I want to validate some fields, Only if a particular field is selected.

My first field is a radio button :

```
<%= f.radio_button :type_doc, '5' %>
<%= f.radio_button :type_doc, '6' %>
<%= f.radio_button :type_doc, '7' %>
```

Then (for example) if I select radio button with type '6', I want to this

```
<%= f.text_field :number_doc, :placeholder => 'Number' %>
```

to be filled.

I have tried like explained in official doc : [Rails active record validations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#conditional-validation)

So, in my doc.rb model I have this :

```
validates :number_doc, presence: true, if: :type_6?

def type_6?
  :type_doc == '6'
end
```

But it doesn't work, I still be able to select :type_doc == 6 and let my field :number_doc empty.

Any ideas ? Thanks

Comment: It's confusing, what is you issue here? Your `number_doc` with empty value or the validation? Is your `number_doc` has a value when you choose one in your `type_doc` radio button?

Comment: `def type_6? return type_doc == '6' end`

Comment: `:type_doc` is a symbol. It will never equal `'6'`.

Comment: Feel free to accept/upvote answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply use a Lambda:

```
 validates :number_doc, presence: true, if: -> { self.type_doc == '6' }
```

Comment: Guess self is not necessary here. it can be just `if: -> { type_doc == '6' }`

Comment: I would be surprised if the block is evaluated in the context of the instance (but this is Rails so you never now). I'd use: `if: -> (r) { r.type_doc == '6' }`

Answer (score 1):

```
   validates :number_doc, presence: true, if: :type_6?    
   def type_6?
     type_doc == '6' 
   end
```

As suggested:-

```
validates :number_doc, presence: true, if: proc { |r| r.type_doc == '6' }
```

Comment: A working solution, but I would suggest cleaning the content of the method to change `return (self.type_doc == '6' ? true : false)` to simply `type_doc == '6'`. Could also be handled by a Proc instead of a method by saying `validates :number_doc, presence: true, if: proc { |r| r.type_doc == '6' }`